# wordpress get db custom postmeta value for compare before updating hook not working

Tags: php, wordpress

```
function my_post_updated($post_id, $post_data)
{

 $val= get_post_meta($$post_id,'c276b415493b81614a98b061f511e8ff',true);
// $val is showing current value not previous one

}
add_action('pre_post_update', 'my_post_updated', 10, 2 );
```

This hook is not firing before post_update so giving updated value. I want to hook before my postmeta update to compare current value and value in db before update and run some condition on it.

Comment: You have `$$post_id` in `get_post_meta(...);`, I guess it should be `$post_id`? Is that a typo?

Comment: @cabrerahector yes,it's a type error. As per wp add_action('pre_post_update', 'my_post_updated', 10, 2 ); should fire befor but it's not